# Word for 'Choosing one over another'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to say

> provides a better option than 'choosing one over the other'.

Or something to that effect; it's the 'choosing one over the other' or 'choosing one over another' that I'm not a fan of.

I was wondering if there was a more concise way to say this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/prefer) has the verb

> **prefer**
>   VERB
>
> **1** Like (one thing or person) better than another or others; tend to choose.
>
> *I prefer Venice to Rome.*